# Re-use variable outside of function?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, global-variables, scope

How can I use return the `$row` array in the below example, so that I can **re-use the variable outside of this function**?

I manage to echo the information inside the function using `$row['columnName']`, but various combinations of `global` and `$GLOBALS`, `return $xyz` and getting variable scope to work for me has me a bit out of my depth. Any answers please?

```
<?php
function getInfo() {

    $query = /* Some SQL Query */;

    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    if($result == false) 
    { 
       user_error("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query"); 
    } 
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    { 
       echo "<p>Sorry, no rows were returned by your query.</p>\n"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        /* What goes here? */
        }
    } 

}
?>
```

Comment: @yes123, too bad you only need 2 votes for a php badge and look jeroen already got 2 upvotes :-).

Comment: @johan: i am under daily cap so unless he picks my answer upvote won't do nothing at me.. and lol what 's the badge you talking about? xD

Comment: Look at your profile, at the bottom you can see the topic where you scored points, if you get a 100 next to a topic you get a bronze badge for being l33t php guru or something like that :=-). I've got mixed feelings about that cap too, it's nice to get there, but it sucks to see all those votes not go anywhere if you lucked out on an answer.

Comment: @johan: acutally i think your contrary, if you lucked out on answer you for sure don't deserve +1000 rep in one day. Other thing is wehn you provide a lot of good answer in a single day: in this condition i don't get this daily cap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return it from your function:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $results[] = $row;    // or do something more with the row
}
return $results;
```

and call your function like:

```
$query_results = getInfo();
```

Comment: +1 for showing the return code :) Probably better then passing as a reference.

Comment: Damn you guys are really fast, can't finish writing and 3 answer appeared

Comment: Well as usual you're all lightning quick, much appreciated. If I then do `$query_results = getInfo();` and test it with `echo $query_results[0]` or `echo $query_results['columnName']` it just returns **Array** - so either I'm doing something wrong, the array is empty, or both :(

Comment: @Joe No, it´s a 2-dimensional array as `$row` itself already is an array. Just do a `var_dump($query_results)` or try `$query_results[0]['columnName']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getInfo() {

    $query = /* Some SQL Query */;

    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    if($result == false) 
    { 
       user_error("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query"); 
    } 
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    { 
       echo "<p>Sorry, no rows were returned by your query.</p>\n"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 

    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

           $data[] = $row;
        }

     return $data;
    } 

}
```

Then you just do: `$mydata = getInfo();`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `$row` directly inside the `while` block, or you can pass it as a *parameter* to another function that performs the row-level processing. First, define the function:

```
function processRow($r)
{
  echo $r['columnName'];
}
```

Then, inside your loop, *call* that function:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  processRow($row);
}
```

Within that function, the value known as `$row` in `getInfo` will be known as `$r`. (You can name the formal parameter `$row` if you want, but I've used a different name here just to illustrate that they don't *need* to have the same name. If you're not clear on variable scope, then giving lots of variables the same name may just serve to confuse yourself more.)